# How to hide Qcheckbox when Qcombox box selects an item?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, qcheckbox

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 590)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('box', self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 75, 181, 20))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")


        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150,160,100,20))
        self.comboBox.addItem("Yes")
        self.comboBox.addItem("No")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")



        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))

        MainWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have created a combobox with "Yes" and "No", I want to hide the checkbox when I select "No" in the combobox, Can anyone help?

I tried to creat a function that when self.comboBox.currentText == "Yes" , run self.checkBox.hide(), but it didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `currentTextChanged` signal that notifies you if the `QComboBox` selection has been changed sending you the new text, then you should only compare it with the text and together with the `setVisible()` method fulfill your requirement.

```
    self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handle_current_text_changed)

def handle_current_text_changed(self, text):
    self.checkBox.setVisible(text == "Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use signals and slots to do this.  Capture the Combobox's editTextChanged signal with a slot hideCheckBox.

`comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(func)`

In the function `func` simply setVisibility to false when the text is "NO" and true when text is "YES".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the checkbox when the `comboBox` state is `HIDE`, for example, and unhide `checkBox` when the combobox state is `UNHIDE`, use an `IF` construction to catch the state of the combobox. Depending on the state, apply one or the other value to the checkbox:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 590)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('box', self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 75, 181, 20))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")


        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150,160,100,20))
        self.comboBox.addItem("UNHIDE")
        self.comboBox.addItem("HIDE")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.hidefunction) # code for connect to function below

    def hidefunction(self):
        text = str(self.comboBox.currentText()) 
        # this is the state of the current text in combobox. Below simple IF block.
        if text == "UNHIDE":
            self.checkBox.setHidden(False) 
        # its HIDE - your checkBox when comboBox changed his state 
        else:
            self.checkBox.setHidden(True) 
        # its HIDE your checkBox when comboBox changed his state 
    
           

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "11"))

        MainWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```